# JS or Jquery create unique span ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a li item with a span inside. I've built an onclick function in the span to grab the parent li's ID to pass into a JSON get request. I'm unsure of how to create a unique ID and read it in the JS function. Since this is built dynamically I didn't build a switch but I feel like i'm missing another option.
The problem here is that I can't capture the Li ID. I've tried this and also tried based on class, but all seem to be failing.

Li object creation:

```
$("#jdLists").append('<li class="bigger" id = "' + item.ID + '">'+ 
  item.GROUP_NAME + 
  '<span title="Remove from list" class=" Sp icon icon-color icon-plus" style="float: right; vertical-align: middle;" '+
  'onclick="spAdd()"></span>' + 
  '</li>');
```

on click function:

```
function spAdd() {
  $(this).closest("li").attr('id');
}
```

Comment: That function doesn't do anything; it fetches the value of "id" but it doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: How do you maintain code like that?!

Comment: that's correct, when I watch in the browser it doesn't grab the value either, which I'm assuming is because it doesn't know which li is sending the request. I haven't added anything else because of this

Comment: @elclanrs yeah its a mess right now only because I'm getting the concept to work, but thanks I'll clean it up now its getting out of hand lol

Comment: When is `spAdd` called, and what calls it? What is assumed to be `this` in that function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try like this:

```
// Should work for most cases
function uniqId() {
  return Math.round(new Date().getTime() + (Math.random() * 100));
}

// Create elements properly and attach click event
// before appending to DOM so it delegates the event
var $li = $('<li/>', {
  'class': 'bigger',
  id: uniqId()
});

var $span = $('<span/>', {
  'class': 'Sp icon icon-color icon-plus',
  title: 'Remove from list',
  text: 'I\'m a span',
  click: function() { 
    alert( $(this).parent().attr('id') );
  }
});

$('#jsLists').append( $li.append( $span ) );
```

It should alert the li's random id on click. Also instead of inline css, add another class for those styles; better, simpler, easier.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/avevim/1/edit (ctrl+enter to refresh and get new id)

Comment: That's brilliant, this is working perfectly. what is the documentation on how you constructed the li and span objects in Jquery. I need to make sure I understand this for future usage

Comment: @atlMapper: Here's the documentation for it. It's the jQuery method. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 4):

Underscore provides a [`uniqueId`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-128) function for cases like this. Rather than being tricky with dates and random numbers, it just keeps a global counter and increments it each time the function is called:

```
var idCounter = 0;
_.uniqueId = function(prefix) {
  var id = '' + ++idCounter;
  return prefix ? prefix + id : id;
};
```